How to avoid the impact of non-core logic (Txl) on test results when using SPECjbb?
SPECjbb is used to evaluate the performance of Java servers. However, from its architecture, it can be seen that in addition to the core logic (Backend) as the evaluation object, the same machine is also deployed with non-core processing logic (Txl) during testing.

This non-core logic will definitely occupy part of the machine's computing resources and interfere with the Backend. How does specjbb exclude this impact and obtain reliable overall throughput results?
